# Parse object won't save when ACL is set

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, acl

I have a variable in my class

```
var newObject = PFObject(className: "Restaurant")
```

When I go to create this object I want to set the ACL for the current user alone.

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
    let userACL = PFACL()
    userACL.setWriteAccess(true, forUserId: currentUser.objectId!)
    userACL.setReadAccess(true, forUserId: currentUser.objectId!)
    userACL.publicReadAccess = false
    userACL.publicWriteAccess = false

    self.newObject = //setValue....
    self.newObject.ACL = userACL 
    self.newObject.saveInBackground()
}
```

When I call saveInBackground(), Im thrown this error

```
[Error]: internal error (Code: 1, Version: 1.11.0)
```

The object will save if I remove:

```
self.newObject.ACL = userACL
```

This is all my code for ACL so if I need to set something in the AppDelegate or online at Parse I have not done that (but also have not read of such requirements). Any help would be appreciated since Ive been going in circles for a while now. Thanks